# How can I print specific page on IOS AirPrint programmatically

Tags: ios, printing, airprint

I have an iOS iPad app which displays a webview where the user has an option to print. While the content which is presented is only one page, garbage pages are being printed after page one which is wasting toner. I would like to only print page 1, but so far, the only solution I could find is to use the showsPageRange = YES option which really doesn't solve my problem.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to do this?

Comment: Is it printing one web page or a PDF filled with pages?

Comment: Specifically, I am trying to print page one of a multi-page webpage printout.   Thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine that the way iOS print works is that it fits all of the content of a webpage on one paper, however it stretches out if you want the content to be spread over multiple pages, is that right?

Comment: It is a multi-page print out.  I just want page one and want to ignore the rest.  Currently, it gives me multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

test this with a button all that you include in the view is print

```
 ///PRINT///
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.ImagentoPrint.bounds.size,    normal, 0.0);

 [self.ImagentoPrint drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.ImagentoPrint.bounds
                         afterScreenUpdates:normal];
UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIPrintInfo *info = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
info.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationLandscape;
info.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto;
UIPrintInteractionController *pic =
[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.delegate = self;
pic.printingItem = snapshotImage;
pic.printInfo = info;

UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"failed... %@ %ld", error.domain, (long)error.code);
    if (completed)
        NSLog(@"completed yes");
    else
        NSLog(@"completed no");
};

[pic presentFromRect:CGRectMake(600, 650, 100, 200) inView:_ImagentoPrint animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```